# user input list python

Tags: python, arraylist, while-loop

## I am trying to get the sum of the output_values, and it is giving me a traceback error

```
output_values = []
while True:
    user_input = input('Please type in your test grades, and follow your input by typing in "done"')
    if user_input == 'done':
        print('All done, here is your average')
        break
    ### here you will insert in the traceback error to prevent your code from crashing due to invalid input
    try:
        val_input = float(user_input)
        if val_input:
            output_values.append(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print('You have typed in an invalid input, please type in your grade as a numerical digit')
        continue
print(output_values)
summation = sum(output_values)
```

Comment: Which line give you error?

Answer (score 1):

You converted `user_input` from `str` to `float` and assign the returning value to `val_input`, and yet when you append to `output_values` you give it `user_input` instead of `val_input`, effectively discarding your conversion.

```
    val_input = float(user_input)
    if val_input:
        output_values.append(user_input)
```

Simply fix it with:

```
    val_input = float(user_input)
    if val_input:
        output_values.append(val_input)
```